# Android Scroll to bottom finish event

Tags: android

i have simple class extends from ScrollView and i want to call listener when scroll is finish on bottom, my code when scroll finish on top and bottom call interface listener, but i like to only call that on bottom finish

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldX, oldY);
    for (OnScrollChangedListener oscl : onScrollChangedListeners) {
        oscl.onVerticalScrollChanged(y);
    }
    if (mScrollStoppedListener != null && y != oldY) {
        checkIfStopped();
    }
}
```

how to detect scrolling on bottom in this method ? my wroted `if` is not correct and could not detect correctly scrolling down

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by this code.

```
View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()+view.getTop()));
if( diff == 0 ){
    Log.i("ScrollView: ", " Finished on bottom of screen");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in such a way...
First, you grab the last child in your ScrollView:

```
View lastChild = (View) scrollView.getChildAt(scrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
```

Then you check whether that view is fully visible in your ScrollView:

```
boolean isFullyScrolled = lastChild.getBottom() <= scrollView.getHeight() + scrollView.getScrollY();
```

So if `isFullyScrolled` is `true` you can notify your listeners.

Comment: Thanks @Ayzen this helpful very simple for me.